# Can I still receive friend requests if my friend list is full?

Tags: puzzle-and-dragons

In order to maximize Pal Points, I want active friends. My leader (Kushinadahime) is a popular one, so I'm in high demand. Unfortunately, I'm getting more friend requests than I have capacity. I'm removing friends who haven't been active for more than a day and accepting pending friend requests. I want to be able to receive friend requests all of the time with which to replace inactive friends. If my friends list is full, can players still send me friend requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other people can still see you as Explorers (5 pt options) when entering a dungeon, and they can select your leader to use (of course, without the leader skill).  Upon completion, the game even asks if you would like to send a friend request.  However, upon pressing "Yes" the game will then reply with a message stating your list is full.  Presumably the request doesn't actually go through because of that.

(Unfortunately I wasn't able to find any official word on it, sorry.)

Comment: Where is the term "Explorer" established?